# Consuming a number into descending groups

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I always struggle with these types of algorithms.  I have a scenario where I have a cubic value for freight and need to split this value into cartons of different sizes, there are 3 sizes available in this instance, 0.12m3, 0.09m3 and 0.05m3.  A few examples;

Assume total m3 is 0.16m3, I need to consume this value into the appropriate cartons.
I will have 1 carton of 0.12m3, this leave 0.04m3 to consume.  This fits into the 0.05m3 so therefore I will have 1 carton of 0.05m, consumption is now complete.  Final answer is 1 x 0.12m3 and 1 x 0.05m3.

Assume total m3 is 0.32m3, I would end up with 2 x 0.12m3 and 1 x 0.09m3.

I would prefer something either in c# or SQL that would easily return to me the results.

Many thanks for any help.

Cheers

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to fill large cartons first, then next largest etc, right?

Comment: Are you also trying to minimize the empty space in the cartons? For example, if you have a total of `8` and carton sizes of `7`, `4`, and `2`, picking the largest first would leave you with two cartons of `7` and `1`, where the second one will have `1` empty space; whereas if you picked 2 cartons of `4`, there would not be any wasted space.

Comment: This does not really look like a task for sql.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Robert Hyndman . Your question is interesting but have you tried to write some code already ? Maybe you would like to share it here also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an algorithm that may be a little messy but I do think it works. Your problem statement isn't 100% unambiguous, so this solution is assuming you want to pick containers so that you minimize the remaining space, when started filling from the largest container.

```
// List of cartons
var cartons = new List<double>
{
    0.12,
    0.09,
    0.05
};

// Amount of stuff that you want to put into cartons
var stuff = 0.32;

var distribution = new Dictionary<double, int>();

// For this algorithm, I want to sort by descending first.
cartons = cartons.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();

foreach (var carton in cartons)
{
    var count = 0;
    while (stuff >= 0)
    {
        if (stuff >= carton)
        {
            // If the amount of stuff bigger than the carton size, we use carton size, then update stuff
            count++;
            stuff = stuff - carton;
            distribution.CreateNewOrUpdateExisting(carton, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, among remaining cartons we pick the ones that will have empty space if the remaining stuff is put in
            var partial = cartons.Where(x => x - stuff >= 0 && x != carton);
            if (partial != null && partial.Count() > 0)
            {
                var min = partial.Min();
                if (min > 0)
                {
                    distribution.CreateNewOrUpdateExisting(min, 1);
                    stuff = stuff - min;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

There' an accompanying extension method, which either adds an item to a dictionary, or if the `Key` exists, then increments the `Value`.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void CreateNewOrUpdateExisting(this IDictionary<double, int> map, double key, int value)
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            map[key]++;
        }
        else
        {
            map.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT

Found a bug in the case where initial stuff is smaller than the largest container, so code updated to fix it.

### NOTE

This may still not be a 100% foolproof algorithm as I haven't tested extensively. But it should give you an idea on how to proceed.

### EDIT EDIT

Changing the condition to `while (stuff > 0)` should fix the bug mentioned in the comments.

Comment: This is awesome and really close.  I just find that anything that divides exactly into the largest carton (0.12) always creates a 0.05 carton, i.e. 0.36 produces 3 x 0.12 and also 1 x .05, 0.24 creates 2 x 0.12 and 1 x 0.05.  But other than this it is perfect.

Comment: It should be fixed if you changed the condition to `while (stuff > 0)`

Comment: This works in most cases but have found a problem when there is a larger carton to be used, i.e. if the m3 is 0.22, this obviously fits into two 0.12m3 cartons.  This process goes, 1x0.12 then drops down a box to 1x0.09 and 1x0.05.  I totally get the logic but if there was a remainder of 0.10 then it should look at the larger carton as it would fit, giving a total of 2x0.12 cartons.  I have tried to play around with the code but have got nowhere. Any update would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rufus L See my previous comment, is this what you meant by your initial post? Thanks